# Material Design List with a lot of information

Tags: material-design, visual-design

Can anyone point to a good example of a material design list where each list item has a bunch of information? I am struggling to put together a block of information that is appealing.

My specific information has to do with vehicle data. Year, Make, Model, Trim, Interior Color, Ext Color, VIN, and some other information as well as notes.

All suggestions welcome.

Comment: Something like that? http://danielnagy.me/md-data-table/

Comment: Trying to keep the information in a list component, where there is no scrolling left and right on a mobile device. Thanks for the link though!

Comment: I would like also such examples. Although the option can be to provide only the most important details, e.g. Year, Model, Color (or whatever is important  for your user) and show additional options on a product page with details. Probably small percentage of users are using ALL parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like what you are looking for are [cards](https://material.io/guidelines/components/cards.html#):

> A card is a sheet of material that serves as an entry point to more detailed information.
>
> Cards may contain a photo, text, and a link about a single subject. They may display content containing elements of varying size, such as photos with captions of variable length.
>
> A card collection is a layout of cards on the same plane.

[image]

Comment: Agree. At least on mobile it's too much information for a table or list.